# HTML Regex to Extract Data

Tags: php, regex

I have a simple question for regex gurus. And yes... I did try several different variations of the regex before posting here. Forgive my regex ignorance. This is targeting PHP.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <h4>
        <a href="somelink.html">some text blah</a>
    </h4>
    I need this text<br />I need this text too.<br />
</div>
<div>
    <h4>
        <a href="somelink.html">some text blah</a>
    </h4>
    I need this text<br />I need this text too.<br />
</div>
<div>
    <h4>
        <a href="somelink.html">some text blah</a>
    </h4>
    I need this text<br />I need this text too.<br />
</div>
```

What I tried that seemed most likely to work:

```
 preg_match_all('/<div><h4><a href=".*">.*<\/a><\/h4>(.*)<br \/>(.*)<br \/>/', $haystack, $result);
```

The above returns nothing.

So then I tried this and I got the first group to match, but I have not been able to get the second.

```
preg_match_all('/<div><h4><a href=".*">.*<\/a><\/h4>(.*)<br \/>/', $haystack, $result);
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `.*` won't match newlines without [the `/s` modifier](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `DOMXPath`, `//div/text()[preceding-sibling::h4]`

Comment: Added multiple repeating lines.

Comment: @user113215 /s worked to get the first match, but the lines repeat. It's only retrieving the first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using **DOM** and XPath for this.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); 

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xp->query('//div/text()') as $n) {
   list($before, $after) = explode('<br />', trim($n->wholeText));
   echo $before . "\n" . $after;
}
```

But If you still decide to take the regex route, this will work for you.

```
preg_match_all('#</h4>\s*([^<]+)<br />([^<]+)#', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: This worked as advertised. The others would not catch repeating groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regex is great. But, some things are best tackled with a parser. Markup is one such example.

Instead of using regex, I'd use an HTML parser, like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

However, if you insist on using regex for this specific case, you can use this pattern:

```
if (preg_match('%</h4>(\\r?\\n)\\s+(.*?)(<br />)(.*?)(<br />)%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $first_text_string = $regs[2];
    $second_text_string = $regs[4];
} else {
    //pattern not found
}
```

Comment: A comparative list of alternatives to `simplehtmldom` (which can be quite slow and cumbersome) [can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/358679)

Comment: FYI, I also recommend RegexBuddy, as I've mentioned previously in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18132398/278976

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want given the exact input you provided.  If you need something more generic please let me know.

```
(.*)<br\s*\/>(.*)<br\s*\/>
```

See here for a live demo http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1i3